# Setting up new Exchange Online users on RDS servers

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, outlook-2010, windows-server-2012-r2

My company is currently migrating our on prem Exchange users to the hosted Exchange Online platform.  Migrating users is easy but we have hit a snag when on boarding new users.  Our environment has multiple RDS servers.  In the past we would setup a users mailbox on one server and when they would log in to another server the settings would follow them.  That does not seem to be the case with Exchange Online.  We are having to logon to each RDS server and manually set them up each time they logon to a new one(only for new users).  If the user had an old on prem Exchange account that we migrated to the cloud then those settings get over-written and their Exchange Online account comes over no problem.  Just trying to figure out a way that will setup the new user EOL accounts when they logon to the new servers.  We are using Roaming profiles too if that helps. Maybe some sort of powershell script that I can modify with the new users names when I am setting them up?

Comment: It sounds like you need to configure [Exchange autodiscover](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900169(v=exchg.150).aspx) entries in DNS, that way the settings get configured whenever the user opens outlook.  if that won't work and you decide you need to create a script to handle defining the settings on all of your servers please give creating it a shot and let us know what problems you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the AutoDiscovery isn´t working correctly. Please check with the [Microsoft Remote Connection analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/) if you see any errors (e.g. as explained in [KB 2404385](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2404385)). [Here](http://o365info.com/autodiscover-flow-in-an-office-365-environment-part-1-of-3-part-29-of-36/) is by the way a good starting point how that should work.